# View function in Solana

Tags: solana-program

In ETH there are function you can read and get a value from without triggering a transaction.

For exemple, isBlacklist is often a view function that returns a boolean when provided an address : true if the address is blacklisted, false otherwise.

I searched but can't find anything similar on Solana. For example, all the "hello world" examples I found worked by triggering a transaction.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly mark functions as `view` in Anchor. Using the TS client you can read the values using the `.view()` method. The documentation is pretty lacking but you can see an example in the original Github PR that implemented it: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/1695