# how can I get the return value of an instruction upon sent the Tx from JS client?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, anchor-client

Having a instruction that return a number:

```
    pub fn get_value(ctx: Context<DataGet>) -> Result<u64> {
        let ret = 0;
         // ... 
        Ok(ret)
    }
```

then, how can I get that Instruction's return value from JS client after send the transaction?

```
    const tx = await configProgram.methods
      .getValue()
      .accounts({  ...  })
      .rpc();  // ? how can I get the return value of 'get_value' instruction ?
```

Is it possible to archive this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Solana you would usually store data or state in an account and then read that from js after you changed it in a transaction.
I would rethink the problem you are having and check if you really need a view function. Usually if you are just calculating something you can probably also do it in the client or if it is a persistent thing you may want to save it in an account.

There are some way on how you can achieve this though.
You can for example log a value and then parse the logs or use a view function in case you are using anchor.

```
.view()
```

Here is a similar question answering the anchor part:
[View function in Solana](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9696/view-function-in-solana)

Comment: Thanks. I know I can pass value through log or parse the transaction. But I just expect a simple/easy way to get the return value.  `.view() ` is new to me, I will try it later.